# How to correctly use ProcessCmdKey in a calculator windows form application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to build a normal calculator in C# Windows Form Application. I want that when I press any numpad key the number will display in the Textbox, like happens in any standard calculator.

So from researching I get this can be done by overriding `ProcessCmdKey` and changing `KeyPreview` property of Form to `true`.

But the **problem** is : When I entirely work with numpad the calculator works fine. But when I combine *mouse-clicking* any number button and then try to again use numpad-keys the number doesn't show up in TextBox.

I have a generic on-click method for number button (it will fire for 0-9 all button click)

```
private void number_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "" + button.Text;
}
```

Add method (like wise method for subtraction, division, multiplication)

```
private void buttonPlusClk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sign = "+";
    operandOne = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

For Form

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

The overridden `ProcessCmdKey` method

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.NumPad0 |
        Keys.NumPad1 |
        Keys.NumPad2 |
        Keys.NumPad3 |
        Keys.NumPad4 |
        Keys.NumPad5 |
        Keys.NumPad6 |
        Keys.NumPad7 |
        Keys.NumPad8 |
        Keys.NumPad9))
    {

        // also not sure about the KeyEventArgs(keyData)... is it ok?
        number_button_Click(keyData, new KeyEventArgs(keyData));
        return true;

    }
    else if(keyData == (Keys.Add))
    {
        buttonPlusClk_Click(keyData, new KeyEventArgs(keyData));
        return true;
    }
    // ... and the if conditions for other operators
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Ask me if you want any other code to see.

---

For future reference get the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) from [GitHub](https://github.com/tintinmj/SampleSmallCalculator) and to recreate the problem do this

1. Press `2` from keyboard numpad
2. Click `+`
3. Press `1` from keyboard numpad (You will not see 1 coming in textbox)
4. Click equals

Comment: I tried to rebuild your problem (with Form.KeyDown) but I dont get your problem.

Comment: Well why `KeyDown`? I overrided the `ProcessCmdKey` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your key handling function. XOR'ing numbers is incorrect when they are not used as flags.
Also, calling the event handler from this function would result in an error because the first arg is not a button.

```
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            int intKey = (int)keyData;
            if (intKey >= 96 && intKey <= 105) // 96 = 0, 97 = 1, ..., 105 = 9
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + (intKey - 96).ToString();
                return true;

            }
            // ... and the if conditions for other operators
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you elaborate *"XOR'ing numbers is incorrect when they are not used as flags"* a little?

Comment: If you look at the binary representation of the 'Keys', you get:        Keys.NumPad0 => 0110 0000
Keys.NumPad1 => 0110 0001
Keys.NumPad2 => 0110 0010
  
When you apply XOR (single pipe) to these, then you xor every bit in those bytes) You end up with 0110 0011, which is Keys.NumPad3.

Comment: XOR'ing all of the numpad keys, results in the integer 111, which is the Key 'Divide'. You can see this with `Keys result = (Keys.NumPad0 | Keys.NumPad1 | Keys.NumPad2 | Keys.NumPad3 | Keys.NumPad4 | Keys.NumPad5 | Keys.NumPad6 | Keys.NumPad7 | Keys.NumPad8 | Keys.NumPad9);`. So, pressing the divide key would have entered your initial if.